# do liberate the memory at the end of the procedure used to something?

Tags: vba, excel

is the fact of liberating an instance of a worksheet at the end of a procedure  useful for something?
here's the code:

```
sub Macro(path as String)

  Dim ws as worksheet
  set ws = thisWorkbook.Sheets("Recap")
  ....
  ...'do actions on the sheet ws
  ...
  set ws = Nothing

end Sub
```

so my question is: if I do not release the object ws, is that it will automatically release? 
`Set ws = Nothing` serves some at the end of the procedure?

thanks

Comment: If you remember music spinning at 33¹⁄₃ rpm, phones that had cords and a VBA that leaked memory like a sieve then set the object to *Nothing* before exiting the sub for peace of mind. If the only cord attached to your phone was for the pre-bluetooth earbuds then you probably shouldn't need it.

Comment: @Jeeped that has to be the best answer to this question I've ever seen. Literally in stitches!

Comment: I think its good practice when you're working with the windows API or COM but generally the VBA garbage collector has you covered.

Comment: If working with Windows API things stay open until the program exits unless the programmer calls `CloseHandle` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is set to nothing on `end sub` / `end function`.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/122259.aspx